# Choose which dummy to drop in feols - fixest package

Tags: r

I have two fixed effect variables and I'm interested in estimating coefficients of one fixed effect, but `feols` automatically drops the first one always.

For example, in my toy data like below:

```r
library(data.table)
library(fixest)
set.seed(1)

test_dt = data.table(
  y = rnorm(12, 15,20),
  x = rnorm(12, 25, 5),
  TIMESLOT = rep(c('BEG','MID','END'),4),
  FIRM = rep(c('A','B','C','D'), 3)
)
print(test_dt)

            y        x TIMESLOT FIRM
 1:  2.470924 21.89380      BEG    A
 2: 18.672866 13.92650      MID    B
 3: -1.712572 30.62465      END    C
 4: 46.905616 24.77533      BEG    D
 5: 21.590155 24.91905      MID    A
 6: -1.409368 29.71918      END    B
```

I'm trying to estimate coefficients of TIMESLOT fixed effect (removing intercept), and I'm not interested in coef of FIRM.

So my first approach was to run

```r
feols(y ~ 0 + i(TIMESLOT) +  i(TIMESLOT, x) + FIRM, test_dt) # WORKS, and drops one of firm
```

Which yields what I need - all of TIMESLOT coefficients.

```r
The variable 'FIRMD' has been removed because of collinearity (see $collin.var).
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: y
Observations: 12 
Standard-errors: IID 
                  Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|) 
TIMESLOT::BEG   -31.539770  107.34824 -0.293808  0.78806 
TIMESLOT::END    16.660959   45.20014  0.368604  0.73690 
TIMESLOT::MID    72.309104   64.56608  1.119924  0.34432 
TIMESLOT::BEG:x   2.672511    4.23945  0.630391  0.57319 
TIMESLOT::END:x   0.477604    1.97274  0.242102  0.82431 
TIMESLOT::MID:x  -1.121334    2.42085 -0.463199  0.67476 
FIRMA           -17.185688   19.01731 -0.903687  0.43277 
FIRMB           -35.705475   25.40943 -1.405206  0.25461 
FIRMC           -17.706701   21.30094 -0.831264  0.46680 
... 1 variable was removed because of collinearity (FIRMD)
```

My real data has lots of unique values of FIRM so I'd like to put it as fixed effect variable. Unfortunately, `feols` removes one of my dummy variable of interest.

For example,

```r
feols(y ~ 0 + i(TIMESLOT) +  i(TIMESLOT, x)| FIRM, test_dt)
```

yields

```r
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: y
Observations: 12 
Fixed-effects: FIRM: 4
Standard-errors: Clustered (FIRM) 
                  Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|) 
TIMESLOT::END    48.200729   63.44549  0.759719  0.50267 
TIMESLOT::MID   103.848874  123.20970  0.842863  0.46120 
TIMESLOT::BEG:x   2.672511    3.39202  0.787882  0.48828 
TIMESLOT::END:x   0.477604    1.75570  0.272030  0.80325 
TIMESLOT::MID:x  -1.121334    2.21219 -0.506888  0.64714 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 9.82348     Adj. R2: -0.468187
                Within R2:  0.403153
```

So now TIMESLOT::BEG is dropped. I would rather want one of firm dummies to be dropped, but I had no success.

Finally,

I saw `y` and `X`, and `fixef_df` arguments in `feols` function and was trying to use this path as my last resort.

However, I'm getting some error messages that I can't interpret.
My trial is like below.

```r
feols(y= test_dt$y, X = test_dt[,.(i(TIMESLOT), i(TIMESLOT,x))], fixef_df = test_dt[,.(i(FIRM, ref ='A'))])

#Error in get("isFixef", env) : argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

What could be the way to manually drop one of dummy variable here?
I'd appreciate your answers.

(fixest package is not tagged in SO currenlty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from the dev: there's no way to manually drop one.